# What is the most user friendly OSM route planning API?

Tags: openstreetmap, r, routing

I ran a workshop last week on [GIS for Transport Applications](https://github.com/Robinlovelace/GIS4TA). In Nick Bearman's tutorial (available from the previous link) we used Google's routing API (via **ggmap**) and [CycleStreets.net](http://www.cyclestreets.net/api/) routing algorithm via my new package **stplanr**. Here's an illustration of what the latter can do in R - love the fact this is all based on open data and open software:

[image: cyclestreets-route]

I'm looking to include additional OSM routing services - which would people recommend?

Comment: So you don't have any single requirement on routing services, except for user friendlyness? What about specific routing profiles? Via points? Turn restrictions? Route instructions? GPX export? Please see the list of [online routers for OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers).

Comment: How will 'user friendly' be defined? From a dev or actual user perspective?

Comment: @Karussell From a developer perspective. I've seen that link before but I'm asking for something different: up-to-date insight from people with recent knowledge of routing APIs about which ones are most user friendly from a user perspective.

Comment: and 'developer friendly' in your case means has a client for R? Sorry, you need to be more specific :)

Comment: No I mean is easy to *create* a client for R. By which I mean: 1) has an intuitive syntax, 2) a wide range of functionality, 3) good performance. Sorry for not being specific, I guess it's simply quite a broad question...